# How to create a real copy of file descriptor stdout and stderr without using unbuffer / script / tee just with bash built-ins?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, stdout, stderr, tee

My goal is to duplicate, redirect all output (`stdout` and `stderr`) of an
application (`apt-get`) to a file while retaining the usual behavior of
the application (`apt-get`), `stdout` and `stderr`.

How to create a real copy of file descriptor `stdout` and `stderr`? I would
like to keep `stdout` and `stderr` as "natural" as possible. I.e. if it was
running for example `apt-get`, I would wish to retain colors and progress
information. [1]

Here is an example. (The wrapper does more stuff, just kept it simple.)

```
#!/bin/bash

temp_dir="$(mktemp --directory)"
logfile="$temp_dir/log"

unbuffer apt-get "$@" 1> >(tee -a "$logfile") 2> >(tee -a "$logfile" >&2)
```

---

Is it possible to achieve this without `unbuffer` / `script` / `tee` just with `bash` built-ins?

(To keep the wrapper simpler and dependent on less external binaries. Otherwise this could cause conflicts with mandatory access control and so forth.)

(Usage of [script(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) in non-interactive scripts is discouraged by its man page.)

---

[1]

```
22% [8 Packages 3,449 kB/7,098 kB 49%]
174 kB/s 4min 57s
```

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu box handy to check, but the flag to look for would be some sort of `--color=always` flag for `apt-get`.

Comment: `tee` is a POSIX utility. If you can't use `tee` then you're less likely to be able to use `mktemp` and `apt-get`. The `tee` utility does not buffer its output.

Comment: Again: If you can run `apt-get` (with everything that _it_ does), you can most certainly use `tee`.

Comment: The most generic way to ask the question is `How to create a real copy of file descriptor stdout and stderr without using unbuffer / script / tee just with bash built-ins?`. The question isn't tied to apt-get. It's merely an example. unbuffer / script / tee are available, but I don't want to use it. Because as said, it causes follow up issues with mandatory access control and more. This is a shell script / bash scripting question. If it's possible to create a real copy of file descriptions stdout and stderr at once without external tools.

Comment: You would have to implement your own `tee`, probably in C or some lower level language.

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do that. Generally, there's very little you can do with just bash built-ins. And even things that may be possible (unlike creating a pty, which bash absolutely doesn't know how to) turn out to be ridiculously complicated. And horrendously slow.

Answer (score 0):

This *POSIX* shell fake `tee` function has no dependencies:

```
faketee() {
   if [ "$1" = '-a' ] ; then 
      shift
      while read -r x ; do 
         echo "$x" >> "$1"
         echo "$x"
      done
   else  
      while read -r x ; do 
         echo "$x" > "$1"
         echo "$x"
      done
   fi
}
```

Test it in `bash` with `ls` on a file that exists, (which outputs one line to *STDOUT*), and a file name that does not, (which outputs another line to *STDERR*):

```
cd /tmp
ls /bin/bash /bin/nosuchfile  1>  >(faketee -a std.log) \
                              2>  >(faketee -a err.log >&2)
```

Output:

```
/bin/bash
ls: cannot access '/bin/nosuchfile': No such file or directory
```

...then run it again with two more such file names:

```
ls /bin/dash /bin/nohowsuchfile  1>  >(faketee -a std.log) \
                                 2>  >(faketee -a err.log >&2)
```

Output:

```
/bin/dash
ls: cannot access '/bin/nohowsuchfile': No such file or directory
```

Now check the log files to see if the ***`-a`****ppend* switch works:

```
grep -n '.' std.log err.log
```

Output indicates appended redirects are where they should be:

```
std.log:1:/bin/bash
std.log:2:/bin/dash
err.log:1:ls: cannot access '/bin/nosuchfile': No such file or directory
err.log:2:ls: cannot access '/bin/nohowsuchfile': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Didn't try to fake `unbuffer` yet...

Comment: Both sides of the `if` are the same code but for one extra `>`.  This seems inelegant, but I haven't found a way around it that wouldn't require putting an `if`, (or an `eval`), in the `while` loop itself, which would be inefficient.